Devise and authenticity_token problem in production
I have trouble making Devise work in production. When I try to register/login, the following error message appears in the logs:
INFO -- : [] Started POST "/users" for x.x.x.x at 2024-10-25 17:13:59 +0000
INFO -- : [] Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
INFO -- : []   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"xbBO-i0Q8RfwaMauQWKQmS5ynMMZ1YDC0WeOZQvParHwqXzOWSKWljOsiSZpNvMX57LZovgNdXU0OP0qpUVorg", "user"=>{"email"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
WARN -- : [] Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
INFO -- : [] Completed 422 Unprocessable Content in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms (0 queries, 0 cached) | GC: 0.0ms)
ERROR -- : [] ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.):

Just to see if the authenticity_token is being sent I have noticed that the CSRF token in the meta tags do not match the one that Rails received in the request.
What is in the source of the registration page:
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="K5MkNhqyz5xvGNhIAlRe31thoUaxLQsyqurk3F7ZS1NCr-2mVzUkrbgeWpyxzA9x3NGhxA70UsVXQrRAntmpIw" />

What is in the request:
"authenticity_token"=>"xbBO-i0Q8RfwaMauQWKQmS5ynMMZ1YDC0WeOZQvParHwqXzOWSKWljOsiSZpNvMX57LZovgNdXU0OP0qpUVorg"

My Apache SSL site config:
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName domain.org
  ServerAlias www.domain.org
  DocumentRoot /path/public
  RailsEnv production
  PassengerRuby /path/.rbenv/shims/ruby

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  <Directory "/path/public">
      Options FollowSymLinks
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile      /path/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile   /path/privkey.pem

  #For RoR "Mongrel"
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

  #Hack for IE
  SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>

In development everything works fine. Could this be some SSL related issue?
Update
If I set config.force_ssl=false then everything starts to work again. So the problem arises when config.force_ssl=true.

Need to provide a more detail. Have you customized anything? What's your configuration, etc.

@dbugger I customized nothing, actually made a separate Rails app from new just with Devise setup. I might add Apache config, but there is nothing other than that.

You did not specify a rails or a devise version but there are multiple different suggestions here: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5652 on how to potentially solve this error, unclear if it is the same actual issue.
